# Scientific data

Tags: csv, wolfram-mathematica

I want to import data from a corrupted CSV file. It contains scientific numbers and it's a big data set with about 300000 rows and 27 columns. When I import it using,

```
Import["data.csv","HeaderLines"->1]
```

the data format is string. So I change it to data table format by

```
StringSplit[ToString[data[[#]]], ";"] & /@ 
 Range[Dimensions[
    Import["data.csv"]][[1]]]
```

and I need to use the first column to analyse the data. But the problem is that this row is
scientific numbers in string type!! I want to change it to numbers. I used this command:

```
 ToExpression[Internal`StringToDouble[fdata[[All, 1]][[#]]]] & /@ 
  Range[291407];
```

But it takes more than hours to do so!!! Do you have any idea how I can do this without wasting of time??

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange network! For future Mathematica-related questions, you can consider asking on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).  Most of the Mathematica-related activity has moved there.

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the CSV file, so we can take a look at it and try to figure out why importing is slow and why everything is read as a string?  This should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
(* read the first 5 rows *)
d = ReadList["data.csv", Table[Number, {27}], 5]


(* read the rows 100 to 150 *)
s = OpenRead["data.csv"];
Skip[s, Record, 99]
d = ReadList[s, Table[Number, {27}], 51]
Close[s]
```

And `d[[All,1]]` will get you the first column.